# User is getting "You tried to lock table '' while opening it, but the table cannot be locked because it is currently in use."

Tags: postgresql, ms-access

Getting this error, with no table listed, when the user logs in to the order system.

The query is, roughly

```
SELECT FormParts.*, qrySomeOtherColumns.*, CBool(0) AS ObjMissing INTO Temp_SessionFormParts
FROM FormParts INNER JOIN qrySomeOtherColumns ON FormParts.ID = qrySomeOtherColumns.FormPartID
WHERE EmpId = EmpID();
```

The data is coming from linked tables with a Postgres back end.

The data is going into the local table "Temp_SessionFormParts"

This is a local table in the front end, so no one else should have access to it.
Everyone else has a copy of the same database, but no one else gets the error.

Where it gets weird is that she only gets the error when she starts the app with our standard shortcut that copies the latest version.

```
copy "\\NASdiskstation\Install\Deploy\pgFrontEnd.accde" "C:\Merge Documents\" 
start "" MSAccess.exe "C:\Merge Documents\pgFrontEnd.accde"
```

But if she starts Access from the Start Menu, and then opens the same database from the selections, it works fine.

Seems to me that those two routes should give the same result since she's already copied the latest to C:.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead an posted this question, since I had it written up, because I've seen this error a few times. So this may be helpful.

Normally, you can't SELECT INTO an existing table. But Access detects that situation and helpfully deletes the table before executing the insert.

Somehow this was failing.

```
DROP TABLE Temp_SessionFormParts
```

before the INSERT fixed the issue.

No idea why it sometimes didn't work for some people or why running Access directly changed that.